# qsort to lexigraphically sort strings in c

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

I'm looking to sort an array of strings using the `stdlib` function `qsort`.

I have the populated array: `char *words[MAX_WORDS];`

and a comparison function:

```
int compare_words(const void *p, const void *q) {
    printf("%s\n", (const char*)p); // For debugging
    return strcmp((const char*)p, (const char*)q);
}
```

Using a `qsort` call: `qsort(words, i, sizeof(char*), compare_words);`

I can tell by the print that I've inserted into the `compare_words` function that qsort isn't passing the proper arguments to `compare_words`. (It prints garbage). Any ideas as to why it's not getting the proper char pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qsort` passes pointers to your array elements, so you are actually getting `const char **` and not `const char*`.

In particular, printing those pointers as `const char*` prints portions of your input array as text, so obviously you're getting garbage.

Comment: So you need: `printf("%s\n", *(const char**)p); return strcmp(*(const char**)p, *(const char**)q);`!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks